# Linking Optional Nodes with Cypher Query in Neo4j 2.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to attach newly created nodes to additional nodes that may or may not exist.  Basically, CREATE A and if B exists, LINK B to A and RETURN A. If B doesn't exist just RETURN A.

This is my Cypher query (the extra WITH clauses are because this is part of a larger query and I'm trying to make sure this sample code works the same way):

```
CREATE (a:A { foo: "bar" })
WITH a

OPTIONAL MATCH (b:B)
WHERE a.foo = b.foo
CREATE UNIQUE b-[:LINK]->a
WITH a

RETURN a
```

This doesn't work since the CREATE UNIQUE fails since b is NULL. Other than breaking it up into multiple queries, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to hack it with foreach...

```
CREATE (a:A { foo: "bar" })
WITH a

OPTIONAL MATCH (b:B)
WHERE a.foo = b.foo
WITH a, collect(b) as bs
FOREACH(b in bs | CREATE UNIQUE b-[:LINK]->a)
WITH a

RETURN a
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Tried to use FOREACH but it complained that NULL wasn't the right type. Didn't occur to me that collect(NULL) would do the trick.

Comment: You can probably also do `[b] as bs`, if you have a lot of values matching in the optional match that might be less eager/more lazy.

Comment: So if b is a collection and I do [b] it doesn't become a collection of collections?

Comment: I meant `WITH a, [b] as bs` instead of collect